# Issue returning proper value

Tags: ruby, scope, return

```
def sum_two(arry, sum)
  p check_sums(sum, arry[0], arry[1..arry.length - 1])
end

def check_sums(target, first_num, remaining_nums)
  result = []
  return result if remaining_nums == []

  remaining_nums.each do |n|
    if first_num + n == target
      result << [first_num, n]
    end
  end
  check_sums(target, remaining_nums[0], remaining_nums[1..remaining_nums.length - 1])
end

my_arry = [2,4,6,1,3,5,7]
my_sum = 6

sum_two(my_arry, my_sum)
```

Above is my solution to a practice interview question.  However, the output is always an empty array (`[]`). My question is seemingly rudimentary as I just need to return the final result array so I must be missing something obvious.  Basically, I can't figure out why its printing an empty array because I feel quite confident the logic is sound.

**UPDATE:**

Below is an updated version of my solution in which I wrap the methods in a class and make result an instance variable so that I can maintain its state throughout the recursive call.  Thanks to @BenE for mentioning that I was resetting the value every time the recursive call went through.  That really cleared it up for me!   Here's my new solution:

```
class SumTwo
  @result = []

  def self.sum_two(arry, sum)
    p SumTwo.check_sums(sum, arry[0], arry[1..arry.length - 1])
  end

  def self.check_sums(target, first_num, remaining_nums)
    return @result if remaining_nums == []

    remaining_nums.each do |n|
      if first_num + n == target
        @result << [first_num, n]
      end
    end
    check_sums(target, remaining_nums[0], remaining_nums[1..remaining_nums.length - 1])
    @result
  end
end
my_arry = [2,4,6,1,3,5,7]
my_sum = 6

SumTwo.sum_two(my_arry, my_sum)
```

Comment: Is the solution supposed to be recursive ?

Comment: What is the interview question?

Comment: @seph from what I understand the question asks him to check whether the sum of two numbers in the array `my_arry` is equal to `my_sum`. If two numbers are equal the sum, then he returns the the two numbers

Comment: The main problem with your recursive function is that the results are stored locally to each function call so basically your results are getting cleared each recursive call.

Comment: @seph The interview question is:  Given an array of numbers and a target sum number, write a function that returns a new array of all the potential pairs of numbers.

Comment: @BenE That totally makes sense.  I'm going to try to wrap it in a class and pass result as an instance variable so its state doesn't change.  Thanks!a

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you don't return the `result` array that you loop on, you only return it when `remaning_nums` is empty, here is a working solution to you code:

```
def sum_two(arry, sum)
  p check_sums(sum, arry[0], arry[1..arry.length - 1],[])
end

def check_sums(target, first_num, remaining_nums,result)
  return result if remaining_nums == []

  remaining_nums.each do |n|
    if first_num + n == target
      result << [first_num, n]
    end
  end
  check_sums(target, remaining_nums[0], remaining_nums[1..remaining_nums.length - 1],result)
  result
end

my_arry = [2,4,6,1,3,5,7]
my_sum = 6

sum_two(my_arry, my_sum)
```

Comment: Thanks but this result is only showing me one possible solution, `[[2,4]]` but I want all possible combinations and I know that `[1, 5]` is another

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return all pairs of numbers in an array whose sum is a given value, I think it's easiest to use the method [Array#combination](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-combination):

```
def sum_two(arry, sum)
  arry.combination(2).select { |i,j| i+j == sum }
end

sum_two [2,4,6,1,3,5,7], 6
  #=> [[2, 4], [1, 5]]

sum_two [*(1..24)], 12
  #=> [[1, 11], [2, 10], [3, 9], [4, 8], [5, 7]]

sum_two [1,3, 6, 8, 2, 9, 3, 5, 7, 8, 16], 17
  #=> [[1, 16], [8, 9], [9, 8]]
```

If you want to eliminate `[8, 9]` or `[9, 8]` in the last example, you could do this:

```
def sum_two(arry, sum)
  arry.uniq.combination(2).select { |i,j| i+j == sum }
end

sum_two [1,3, 6, 8, 2, 9, 3, 5, 7, 8, 16], 17
  #=> [[1, 16], [8, 9]]
```

Comment: This is the approach i would have taken with Ruby. From the original question, it's still unclear if the answer needs to be a recursive solution; without using methods such as combinations.

Comment: Thanks @BenE!  This is good to know but I was solving it without using built-in ruby methods.  The recursive call was just one approach and I know that as the set of numbers for an array increase you face issues with stack overflow.  But I will definitely add this to my possible solutions for this.

Comment: "...I was solving it without using built-in Ruby methods."  Hmmm. It's quite challenging to write a program in Ruby without using any of its built-in methods.  :-) What's the difference between using `each` and `combination`?

Comment: Combination is more succinct ;-).  But I've heard of many instances where the interview would specifically request that you don't use a built in method for a particular challenge.  That's the only reason why I wouldn't use combination.

Comment: But what if they *expect* you to use `combination` or something similar?  You will not impress by suggesting something less Riby-like. In any event, there was nothing in the question that suggested you didn't want certain methods to be used.